# Norwegian naming conventions

Tags: research-methods, naming-convention, naming, ethnicity, norway

I'm looking for a comprehensive explanation of Norwegian naming conventions, specifically relating to multiple given names and middle names, etc., as opposed to Surnames, patronymics, etc. (even if they fall in the "middle" of the individual's "full" name).

I'm especially interested in trends and practices within the past 50 years or so, 1980's to present.

I'm not looking for lists of common names.  I'm specifically looking for descriptions or explanations of how names are generally selected, why multiple (given, first, middle) names are or are not used, etc.

Does anyone know of a good resource to explain common naming conventions for modern Norwegian names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try contacting an ex-pat organization like "The Sons of Norway" if you can.  Since they often have maintaining culture as part of their mission, explaining recent naming conventions might be right up their alley.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I've emailed them, we'll see...

Comment: Success, they replied back with some excerpts of some books they have on file, that were exactly what I needed.